# "Pattern Match expression not valid" error for .Execute FindText

Tags: vba, ms-word

Here is the code which was working yesterday:

```vb
Sub TestError()

Dim Error As Integer

    With Selection.Find
      .ClearFormatting
      .Font.Bold = True
      .Execute FindText:="Error! Reference source not found."

        If .Found = True Then
           Error = MsgBox("Reference Source error detected - continue with macro?", 4)
              If Error = 7 Then
              Exit Sub
             End If
         End If

    End With

End Sub
```

It should search for "Error! Reference source not found.", and if the document contains that string then it should throw a warning and ask the user if they want to continue.

Worked yesterday, now it's throwing

> "The Find What text contains a Pattern Match expression which is not valid"

on `.Execute FindText`.

Usually this error comes from something like a wildcard search with an unclosed set of brackets or something.

(I have tried turning it off and on.)

Comment: Working perfectly fine for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is most likely that you've previously done a *wildcard* Find and have not re-set that (despite what you say to the contrary):

```
Sub TestError()
Dim Error As Long
With Selection.Find
  .ClearFormatting
  .Font.Bold = True
  .MatchWildcards = False
  .Text = "Error! Reference source not found."
  .Execute
  If .Found = True Then
    Error = MsgBox("Reference Source error detected - continue with macro?", 4)
    If Error = 7 Then Exit Sub
  End If
End With
End Sub
```